# pexpect: failed to get the string after the marker

Tags: python, pexpect

Below is the code I used, I want to use pexpect to get the entire output of a commmand running in a ssh section:

I have tried many ways to get the output of the command, but it always return the string before the marker, i can't get the string after the marker, I need to get the entire output of the command. please help me with above function run_command_and_return_status_and_output

```
import pexpect
import sys
def ssh_login(ssh_host, ssh_username, ssh_password, timeout=10):
    ssh_command = f"ssh {ssh_username}@{ssh_host}"
    child = pexpect.spawn(ssh_command, timeout=timeout)

    try:
        # Expect the SSH password prompt
        index = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, 'password:', pexpect.EOF], timeout=timeout)

        if index == 0:
            raise Exception("SSH connection timeout")

        if index == 1:
            # Send the SSH password
            child.sendline(ssh_password)
            # Expect the shell prompt after successful login
            index = child.expect(['7503', pexpect.EOF], timeout=timeout)

            if index == 0:
                return child  # Successfully logged in

            raise Exception("Authentication failed")

    except Exception as e:
        child.close()
        raise e

def run_command_and_return_status_and_output(child, command, success_marker, failure_marker, timeout=10):
    status = "Pass"  # Initialize status as Pass, assuming the command will pass
    output = ""

    try:
        # Send the command
        child.sendline(command)
        # Expect the output
        index = child.expect([success_marker, failure_marker, pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT], timeout=timeout)

        if index == 0:
            status = "Pass"


        if index == 1:
            status = "Fail"


        if index not in [0, 1]:
            status = "Exception"

        output = child.before.decode('utf-8')+child.after.decode('utf-8')
        if output:
            # Remove the command from the output
            output = output.replace(command, "")

    except Exception as e:
        status = "Exception"
        output = str(e)

    finally:
        return status, output


def run_command_and_return_status_and_output(child, command, success_marker, failure_marker, timeout=10):
    status = "Pass"  # Initialize status as Pass, assuming the command will pass
    output = ""
    try:
        # Send the command
        child.sendline(command)
        # Expect the output
        index = child.expect([success_marker, failure_marker, pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT], timeout=timeout)

        if index == 0:
            status = "Pass"
        elif index == 1:
            status = "Fail"

        # Get the entire output, including before and after
        output = child.before.decode('utf-8') + child.after.decode('utf-8')

    except Exception as e:
        status = "Exception"
        output = str(e)

    finally:
        return status, output

# Example usage
ssh_host = "your host"
ssh_username = "your username"
ssh_password = "your password"

child = ssh_login(ssh_host, ssh_username, ssh_password)
command = "ifconfig -a"
success_marker = "lo"
failure_marker = "xxx"
timeout = 10

status, output = run_command_and_return_status_and_output(child, command, success_marker, failure_marker, timeout)
print("Status:", status)
print("Output:", output)

# Close the SSH connection
child.close()
```

Comment: Can you provide giving and expected output?

Comment: please post a [repro]

Comment: @pynexj I update with miminal steps

Comment: `child.before` is for before, `.after` is for after.

Comment: @pynexj it doesn't work, I added .after and  forget to update my code , now updated, can you have a try with it. it still not show the string after the marker

Comment: you should `expect()` something like the shell prompt. then the info you are interested would be included in `.before`. the data in `.after` are not guaranteed to include all current output data from the spawned process.